# Get type/class of a Set<Type> members

Tags: grails, groovy

My class `User.groovy` in a grails projects contains the following Set

```
Set<GlobalRole> globalRoles
static hasMany = [globalRoles: GlobalRole]
```

whereas `GlobalRole` is an enum

```
enum GlobalRole  {
    GLOBALROLE_MGR('Manager'),
    ...
    GlobalRole(String id) {
        this.id = id
    }
}
```

in one of the views (edit) i present the following select on the user

```
from="${com.path.classification.GlobalRole?.values()}"
```

which works fine.
however: this needs to be dynamic and needs to work with various enums. All of them are in

```
com.path.classification
```

eg

```
com.path.classification.LocalRole
com.path.classification.InvestmentType
```

the only thing i have available is the member of the hosting class (here user), for example:

```
${domainInstance}?.${property.name}
```

which yields the Set `user.globalRoles`

my question: is there a way to deduct the values of an enumeration by having access to a Set containing some of them?

e.g. something in the way of this (not working!)

```
user.globalRoles.elements.class
```

to be able to generate the source dynamically?

Comment: why don't you try `user.globalRoles.iterator().next().class` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
${userInstance?.domainClass.getPropertyByName('mySetName').getReferencedPropertyType().values()}
```

to get a list of all possible enum values.